# Message Not Received

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

There is an issue with my application where it seems like the ViewModel is not receiving the request (at least from the logs). However, this is only the case for one computer. Other computers seem to be fine and are able to process the request. I do not see the problem with the code, perhaps there is something about GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger that i am not aware of?

**Code:**
MainApplication

```
public string LocalWebServerResp(HttpListenerRequest req){
            logger.Info("LocalWebServerResp - Start");
            string resp = "ok";
            if (req.QueryString.Count > 0)
            {
                Messenger.Default.Send<ViewModelRequest>(new ViewModelRequest(ViewModelRequest.RequestType.NewView));
            }
            logger.Info("LocalWebServerResp - End");
            ....
    }
```

ViewModel

```
ViewModel(){
    ....
    Messenger.Default.Register<ViewModelRequest>(this, this.OnViewModelRequest);
    ....
}

private void OnViewModelRequest(ViewModelRequest request)
{
    logger.Info("ViewModel Request Recieved");
    ....
}
```

Logs:

```
LocalWebServerResp - Start
LocalWebServerResp - End
```

Comment: Maybe QueryString is coming empty, add another log message and check if the code enters the `if (req.QueryString.Count > 0)` block.

Comment: Thank you, I was so focused on the other code that I missed that.